# How can I refactor these IO operations in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I just made a script that takes some values from a TSV file and formats them differently. The script looks like this:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, QuasiQuotes #-}

import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO

tsvToPat tsv = T.unlines $ map (makePat . (T.replace "-" " ") . head . (T.splitOn "\t")) (T.lines tsv)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  pantone <- TIO.readFile "../data/maps/pantone/pantone.tsv"
  xkcd <- TIO.readFile "../data/maps/xkcd/rgb.txt"
  jaffer <- TIO.readFile "../data/maps/jaffer/master.tsv"
  TIO.putStr $ tsvToPat pantone
  TIO.putStr $ tsvToPat xkcd
  TIO.putStr $ tsvToPat jaffer


makePat :: T.Text -> T.Text
makePat pat = T.concat [ "{\"label\":\"COLOR\",\"pattern\":[{\"lower\":\""
                       , pat
                       , "\"}]}"
                       ]
```

but I'm struggling with thinking about how to refactor everything in the main function. What I want to do is something like:

```hs
maps :: [FilePath]
maps = [ "../data/maps/pantone/pantone.tsv"
       , "../data/maps/xkcd/rgb.txt"
       , "../data/maps/jaffer/master.tsv"
       ]

main = map (TIO.putStr . tsvToPat . TIO.readFile) maps
```

Which won't work, because I'm guessing it's mixing IO operations with pure functions. Is there some magic monadic bind operator I should be using here?

Comment: hint: use `mapM` ;)

Comment: @lsmor `mapM` is almost always wrong when the inside type is `()`, in which case `mapM_` should be used instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The monadic binding operator you're looking for is `<=<` from `Control.Monad`.  It acts like function composition for monad operators.  You would also need to upgrade your `map` to a monadic mapping function `mapM_`.  For example, ignoring the `tsvToPat` bit, you could write:

```
main = mapM_ (TIO.putStr <=< TIO.readFile) maps
```

It can be a little tricky to figure out how to squeeze a pure function like `tsvToPat` in there.  One way is to make it monadic by writing `return . tsvToPat`, so you get:

```
main' :: IO ()
main' = mapM_ (TIO.putStr <=< return . tsvToPat <=< TIO.readFile) maps
```

Note that the precedence of `.` here is higher than `<=<`.

Even though that version makes everything pretty clear, it  can actually be simplified to:

```
main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ (TIO.putStr . tsvToPat <=< TIO.readFile) maps
```

Answer (score 4):

Actions in `do` blocks desugar to calls to `>>=`, and there's a flipped version of that called `=<<`. To run a list of IO actions, use `mapM_`. Put those concepts together and you get this:

```
main = mapM_ (\x -> TIO.putStr . tsvToPat =<< TIO.readFile x) maps
```

Comment: you've missed the list argument!!

Comment: @lsmor oops, fixed now.